# How to extract 'Week Number' and 'Day Number' from Date if Start Day is 'Monday' in a Month SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am extracting below from a date:

Week Number
Day Number

Where start day of my Week is Monday.

For Example the date is : '1st May 2019' or '2019-05-01'

Then

Week Number = 1
Day Number = 3

Because the day is Wednesday on 1st May 2019.

I am using MS SQL Server 2012.
and used below code from net to get Week Number.
I get the Week Number from this but i do not understand what actually it is doing.

```
select datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)), 0), @date - 1) + 1
```

Can anyone explain it to me and tell me how to extract the Day Number.

Answer (score 0):

This select will give you the `@date` *day of week* (1: Monday, 7: Sunday), regardless of your @@DATEFIRST set [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments):

```
select (DATEPART(DW, @date) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 as [Day of Week]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `datefirst`, you can simply do:

```
set datefirst 1;  -- "1" = "Monday"

select datepart(week, getdate()), datepart(weekday, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned how to get the day-of-week.

In terms of your code for getting week-of-month:

```
select datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)), 0), @date - 1) + 1
```

To my eye it appears to get the number of full months elapsed between day zero and the current date, giving us a month-serial.

Then adds zero months to this figure (which is apparently being used to cast the month-serial back to a date representing the beginning of the current month), giving us a beginning-of-month date.

It then gets the number of full weeks elapsed between day zero and the beginning-of-month date, giving us a week-serial.

The week-serial is then cast back to a date representing the beginning-of-week date, representing the Monday on or prior to the beginning-of-month date.

It then gets the difference, in weeks, between the monday-on-or-prior date and the day before the current date, and adds 1 (so that the first week of the month is represented as Week 1).

It sounds like a plausible algorithm, but I wouldn't endorse it without testing and inspecting the intermediary values, however, or unless you have found it from an authoritative source.

Answer (score 0):

Check This-

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEPART(DW,GETDATE())-1,0),7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have constructed the query as per your need. It works fine.

> **NOTE** : Sunday is considered as 1st day of the week and Saturday is considered as 7th day of the week

```
DECLARE @dt datetime='2019-05-01'
DECLARE @Weekday INT

if(((DATEPART(DW, @dt) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 +2) =8)
    SET @Weekday =1 
else 
    SET @Weekday = ((DATEPART(DW, @dt) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 +2)

select DATEPART(week, @dt)- DATEPART(week, CONVERT(CHAR(6), @dt, 112)+'01')+ 1 AS [Week Number], @Weekday AS [Day of Week]
```